# Place boxes for user choice as in surveys

Tags: symbols

[image]

I want to place boxes between two text parts. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Use amssymb and `\square`.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\textbf{How satisfied are you with the temperature in your office today?}

\center{
Very Satisfied  $\square\hspace{5pt}\square\hspace{5pt}\square\hspace{5pt}\square\hspace{5pt}\square\hspace{5pt}\square\hspace{5pt}\square$  Very Dissatisfied}

\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image]

Comment: you might use math spaces inside math